# Retrieving the time that an access token was generated?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm trying to get the claim that contains the token creation date... I've tried the following:

```
var createdDate = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("IssuedUtc");

var createdDate = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("iss");

var createdDate = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationInstant);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JWT as the access token format, you can use the `iat` claim.

When using the default opaque format, the creation date is not stored as a claim, but as an authentication property. You can retrieve it by using the `AuthenticationManager` API:

```
var result = await contextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var date = result.Properties.IssuedUtc;
```

Note: the second option also works with JWT, just replace the `OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` constant by `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.